# Built in Python hash() function

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hash

Windows XP, Python 2.5:

```
hash('http://stackoverflow.com') Result: 1934711907
```

Google App Engine (http://shell.appspot.com/):

```
hash('http://stackoverflow.com') Result: -5768830964305142685
```

Why is that? How can I have a hash function that will give me same results across different platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac)?

Comment: this is owe to the fact your winxp is a 32bit platform while google's is 64 bit

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hash#module-hashlib) as `hash()` [was designed to be used to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash):

> quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup

and therefore does not guarantee that it will be the same across Python implementations.

Comment: Aren't the hash functions in `hashlib` a bit slow for non-cryptographic use?

Comment: They are actually very slow compared to general purpose hash functions such as Jenkins, Bernstein, FNV, MurmurHash, and many others. If you're looking to make your own hash table-like structure, I suggest looking at uthash.h http://uthash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Benchmarks: `hash` 95 ns, `binascii.crc32` 570 ns, `hashlib.md5.digest()` 1.42 us, `murmur.string_hash` 234 ns

Comment: `hash` uses a new randomly generated salt value with each python session. So it will change between python sessions.

Comment: It's not even guaranteed to be the same across python processes started on the same machine! Try running `echo "print(hash('hej'))" | python3 -` a few times and notice the different output each time (python 3.6).

Answer (score 93):

As stated in the documentation, built-in hash() function is *not* designed for storing resulting hashes somewhere externally. It is used to provide object's hash value, to store them in dictionaries and so on. It's also implementation-specific (GAE uses a modified version of Python). Check out:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> b = Foo()
>>> hash(a), hash(b)
(-1210747828, -1210747892)
```

As you can see, they are different, as hash() uses object's `__hash__` method instead of 'normal' hashing algorithms, such as SHA.

Given the above, the rational choice is to use the [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) module.

Comment: Thank you! I came here wondering why I would always get different hash values for identical objects resulting in unexpected behaviour with dicts (which index by hash+type rather than checking for equality). A quick way to generate your own int hash from hashlib.md5 is `int(hashlib.md5(repr(self)).hexdigest(), 16)` (assuming that `self.__repr__` has been defined to be identical iff objects are identical). If 32 bytes are too long, you can cut of course the size down by slicing the hex string prior to conversion.

Comment: On second thought, if `__repr__` is unique enough, you could just use `str.__hash__` (i.e. `hash(repr(self))`) as dicts don't mix up non-equal objects with the same hash. This only works if the object is trivial enough that the repr can represent identity, obviously.

Comment: So, in your example with two objects `a` and `b`, how could I use the hashlib module to see that the objects are identical?

Comment: @pluma @Garett The real reason is that: [Instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-hashable). If this is not your desired behavior, you should just [implement `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` methods in your class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2909119/1916449).

Answer (score 32):

The response is absolutely no surprise: in fact

```
In [1]: -5768830964305142685L & 0xffffffff
Out[1]: 1934711907L
```

so if you want to get reliable responses **on ASCII strings**, just get the lower 32 bits as `uint`. The hash function for strings is 32-bit-safe and *almost* portable.

On the other side, you can't rely at all on getting the `hash()` of any object over which you haven't explicitly defined the `__hash__` method to be invariant.

Over ASCII strings it works just because the hash is calculated on the single characters forming the string, like the following:

```
class string:
    def __hash__(self):
        if not self:
            return 0 # empty
        value = ord(self[0]) << 7
        for char in self:
            value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
        value = value ^ len(self)
        if value == -1:
            value = -2
        return value
```

where the `c_mul` function is the "cyclic" multiplication (without overflow) as in C.

Answer (score 21):

Most answers suggest this is because of different platforms, but there is more to it. From [the documentation of `object.__hash__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> By default, the `__hash__()` values of `str`, `bytes` and
>   `datetime` objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value.
>   Although they remain constant within an individual Python process,
>   they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python.
>
> This is intended to provide protection against a denial-of-service
>   caused by carefully-chosen inputs that exploit the worst case
>   performance of a dict insertion, O(n²) complexity. See
>   http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html for details.
>
> Changing hash values affects the iteration order of `dicts`, `sets`
>   and other mappings. Python has never made guarantees about this
>   ordering (and it typically varies between 32-bit and 64-bit builds).

Even running on the same machine will yield varying results across invocations:

```
$ python -c "print(hash('http://stackoverflow.com'))"
-3455286212422042986
$ python -c "print(hash('http://stackoverflow.com'))"
-6940441840934557333
```

While:

```
$ python -c "print(hash((1,2,3)))"
2528502973977326415
$ python -c "print(hash((1,2,3)))"
2528502973977326415
```

---

See also the environment variable [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED):

> If this variable is not set or set to `random`, a random value is used
>   to seed the hashes of `str`, `bytes` and `datetime` objects.
>
> If `PYTHONHASHSEED` is set to an integer value, it is used as a fixed
>   seed for generating the `hash()` of the types covered by the hash
>   randomization.
>
> Its purpose is to allow repeatable hashing, such as for selftests for
>   the interpreter itself, or to allow a cluster of python processes to
>   share hash values.
>
> The integer must be a decimal number in the range `[0, 4294967295]`.
>   Specifying the value `0` will disable hash randomization.

For example:

```
$ export PYTHONHASHSEED=0                            
$ python -c "print(hash('http://stackoverflow.com'))"
-5843046192888932305
$ python -c "print(hash('http://stackoverflow.com'))"
-5843046192888932305
```

Comment: This is only true for Python 3.x, but since Python 3 is the present and the future and this is the only answer that addresses this, +1.

Comment: This is a sound way to test machine-independence - thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Hash results varies between 32bit and 64bit platforms

If a calculated hash shall be the same on both platforms consider using

```
def hash32(value):
    return hash(value) & 0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 6):

At a guess, AppEngine is using a 64-bit implementation of Python (-5768830964305142685 won't fit in 32 bits) and your implementation of Python is 32 bits. You can't rely on object hashes being meaningfully comparable between different implementations.

Answer (score 6):

This is the hash function that Google uses in production for python 2.5:

```
def c_mul(a, b):
  return eval(hex((long(a) * b) & (2**64 - 1))[:-1])

def py25hash(self):
  if not self:
    return 0 # empty
  value = ord(self[0]) << 7
  for char in self:
    value = c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
  value = value ^ len(self)
  if value == -1:
    value = -2
  if value >= 2**63:
    value -= 2**64
  return value
```

Comment: Can you share any context about what this hash function is used for and why?

Answer (score 5):

What about sign bit?

For example:

Hex value `0xADFE74A5` represents unsigned `2919134373` and signed `-1375832923`.
Currect value must be signed (sign bit = 1) but python converts it as unsigned and we have an incorrect hash value after translation from 64 to 32 bit.

Be careful using:

```
def hash32(value):
    return hash(value) & 0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 3):

Polynomial hash for strings. `1000000009` and `239` are arbitrary prime numbers. Unlikely to have collisions by accident. Modular arithmetic is not very fast, but for preventing collisions this is more reliable than taking it modulo a power of `2`. Of course, it is easy to find a collision on purpose.

```
mod=1000000009
def hash(s):
    result=0
    for c in s:
        result = (result * 239 + ord(c)) % mod
    return result % mod
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) might be used to initialize the hash values.

Try:

```
PYTHONHASHSEED python -c 'print(hash('http://stackoverflow.com'))'
```