# removing an instance of an object in python list

Tags: python, list, compare

I Think this should work but its giving me an error. 
I have a list that contains objects of class `node`. I have two different lists

1. open_list
2. node_list.( they are not the same lengthwise, ordering wise)

When I find a specific node in the `open_list` I need to delete it from the `node_list`. I know that the lists have addresses to the objects stored in them

so when i try to do

```
removed = open_list.pop(min_index) 
node_list.remove(removed)
```

it gives me an error saying

```
node_list.remove(removed)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

but the list just contains addresses that act like pointers right? it should match up the same addresses. i printed out the address of `removed` and the whole `node_list` (only 10 items for now don't fear) 
print out: (the last item in node_list matches the address of removed:

```
removed: <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A440>
node_list: [<__main__.node instance at 0x01246E90>, <__main__.node instance at 0x01246EE0>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A300>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A328>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A350>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A378>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A3A0>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A3C8>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A3F0>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A418>, <__main__.node instance at 0x0124A440>]
```

Thanks

#### **follow-up Q**

so I want to check if the node i want to remove exists in the node_list. when i looked up some simple list functions on http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

`list.index(x)` and `remove.index(x)` both give an error if the element is not in the list. this caused my program to stop running. 
to bypass this, can i use this statement before the `.remove()`: `node in node_list` i think the `in` checks to see if an element is part of a list and returns a bool.
just double checking 
thanks,

Answer (score 18):

This is happening because what you understand as identifying features of two instances of your `Node` class, is not how python understands it.

The problem lies here. Suppose you asked python `5==5`, python would return `True`. This is because python knows about `int`s. However, `Node` is a custom class that you defined, so you need to tell python when two `Node` objects are the same. Since you (probably) haven't, python defaults to comparing their locations in memory. Since two separate instances will be in two different memory locations, python will return `False`. If you are familiar with Java at all, this is like the difference between `==` and `.equals(...)`

In order to do this, go into your `Node` class and define the `__eq__(self, other)` method, where `other` is expected to be another instance of `Node`.

For example, if your nodes have an attribute called `name` and two nodes that have the same name are considered to be the same, then your `__eq__` could look like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    myName = self.name
    hisName = other.name
    if myName == hisName:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Of course, the more elegant way of writing that same function is:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.name == other.name
```

When this is done, your error should disappear

**EDIT 1**: In response to [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)'s comment

```
class Node: pass
a = [Node(), Node()]
b = a[:]
b.remove(a.pop(0))
```

This will work. But upon closer inspection, it becomes evident that a[0] and b[0] are in fact the same object. This can be verified by calling `id(a[0])` and comparing it with `id(b[[0])` to confirm that they are indeed the same

**EDIT 2**: In response to the OP's follow up question (added to the original question as edit)

Yes, the object not existing in the list will cause an error which would normally stop program flow. This can be solved in either of the following two ways:

```
if x in my_list:
    my_list.remove(x)
```

OR

```
try:
    my_list.remove(x)
except:
    pass
```

The second method attempts to remove `x` from `my_list` and if that results in an error, ignores the error

Comment: so just one line like `__eq__(self, node)`. hmm.. good to learn that about python. thanks!

Comment: Nono... not just one line. What I posted was simply the signature of the function. You need to fully define it (see my edited post)

Comment: ohhh.. okay yea i was reading up on this function in python library and then your example helps. thanks!

Comment: I'd be slightly surprised if this were the cause.  Even without defining `__eq__`, `class Node: pass; a = [Node(), Node()]; b = a[:]; b.remove(a.pop(0))` should work, I think.

Comment: btw i have a quick follow up q if you could check it out.. thankss.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: yeah, they're the same object.  I thought that was the original puzzle, namely that there were two references to the same object at 0x0124A440, and for some reason that object couldn't be removed from `node_list`.  I find the OP's post somewhat confusing, though, so perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @DSM: OP seems to be new to python (and SO) and as a result may not know to differentiate in a question between the same object and equal objects

Answer (score 4):

In response to your followup, yes `in` will check for membership in a list, so:

```
if removed in node_list: node_list.remove(removed)
```

will not give you the error.  Alternatively, you could trap the error:

```
try:
    node_list.remove(removed)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read the question right, python's default of comparing the memory locations is the behavior he is looking for, but is not getting.  Here's a working example where a custom class is defined `Node`,  it show's that there is no need for the `__eq__(self, other)`.

```
class Node(object):
    pass

open_node_list = []
node_list = []

for i in range(10):
    a_node = Node()
    open_node_list.append(a_node)
    node_list.append(a_node)

removed = open_node_list.pop()
node_list.remove(removed)
```

I can't be sure, because you did not show where your `open_node_list` and `node_list` were defined, but I suspect that the lists themselves reference the same list object.  If that's the case, the popping from `open_node_list` also pops from `node_list`, therefore the node will no longer exist when you call `remove`.  Here is example in which `node_list` and `open_node_list` are really the same list and so changes to one affect the other:

```
class Node(object):
  pass

open_node_list = []
node_list = open_node_list # <-- This is a reference, not a copy.

open_node_list.append(Node())
print(node_list)
```

One way you can copy a list is:

```
node_list = open_node_list[:]
```

Comment: I don't think i referenced them. they are separate global lists. I usually just append some nodes from node_list to the open list after some conditions are met. they do contain references to the same objects tho.

Comment: open_list = [] 
closed_list = []
node_list = []. go through a loop to initialize a node list. then do other stuff and append to the open_list if i need to. btw i have a quick follow up q if you could check it out.. thanks.