# Remove from the tail of a linked list (Python)

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I'm new to Python and am having trouble implementing a function to remove the last node from a linked list. This is the code I have so far (I'm coding on an online platform called Coderunner which already has some background code implemented for me, such as the Node class):

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print_all(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.get_data())
            current = current.get_next()

    def add(self, item): 
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node      

    def remove_from_tail(self): 
        current = self.head
        prev = current
        while current != None:
            current = current.get_next()
            prev.set_next(current.get_next())
            return current
```

When running the following code:

```
my_list = LinkedList() 
my_list.add('Car') 
my_list.add('Bike') 
my_list.add('Truck') 
result = my_list.remove_from_tail() 
print('Removed:', result) 
my_list.print_all()
```

I get:

```
Removed: <__main__.Node object at 0x1063650>
Bike
Truck
```

Can anyone suggest where I've gone wrong? It seems like the node object gets printed but not the value inside the node. Thanks in advance for assistance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  You haven't included class **Node**.  You haven't included the code that's printing "Removed:".  It's likely that you're printing the Node object, rather than its name.

Comment: You should post the `Node` class.

Comment: The Node class is not given to me, instead, the code I implement needs to work with what I assume would be a generic implementation of the Node class in python.

Comment: related [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456637/removing-an-instance-of-an-object-in-python-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456637/removing-an-instance-of-an-object-in-python-list)

Comment: I'm still not clear on what output you want.  Car->Bike->Truck and then to remove Truck.  Or Truck->Bike->Car and then remove the Car.

Answer (score 0):

The value that the method remove_from_trail returns is of type Node. When you print it you are printing that Node object. You need to access the value inside the node, you can use:

```
dir(result)
```

to see what methods and attributes does the object have, and then call the attribute that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sorry I've just realized that the output code block cannot be edited - it is one of the tests that are run to check that my code is implemented correctly. So the code that gets fetched from the remove_from_tail function needs to be in the correct format for the test: result = my_list.remove_from_tail()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code will remove all nodes from the list. Try something like:

```
def remove_from_tail(self): 
    current = self.head
    prev = current
    while current.get_next() != None: #the last element will have next == None
        prev = current
        current = current.get_next()
    # At this point, current will be pointing to the last element in the list
    prev.set_next(None)
    return current
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried implementing your code edit but I'm still getting the exact same output. With that said, one of the "tests" that are run to check if my code is implemented correctly works now, which was this test:                                                                                           
    'my_list = LinkedList()
    my_list.add(800)
    my_list.add(700)
    my_list.add(600)
    my_list.add(500)

    my_list.remove_from_tail()

    my_list.print_all()'

Comment: Sorry, the code used for testing successfully was:

`my_list = LinkedList()
 
my_list.add(800) 
my_list.add(700) 
my_list.add(600) 
my_list.add(500)
 
my_list.remove_from_tail()
 
my_list.print_all()` 

however the other test code: `my_list = LinkedList()

my_list.add('Car')
my_list.add('Bike')
my_list.add('Truck')

result = my_list.remove_from_tail()                                         print('Removed:', result)
my_list.print_all()`

still produces the same output.

Comment: @blue_eclipse the problem is in `print('Removed:', result)`. Try `print('Removed:', result.get_data())`

Comment: what if the list only has one element?  in that case, the above code doesn't change anything.