# deleting duplicates in an list of objects by attribute in python

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

I have a function for which I would like to go through a list of custom objects (with given midpoints) one at a time and take objects with unique midpoints and put them in a new list.  The following code gives me an error that the list has no attribute called 'midPoint', but I am not sure how to get the code to search the list for objects with matching midpoints. Does anyone have recommendations?

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, midPoint=[0,0]):
        self.midPoint = midPoint

obj1 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj2 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2])
obj3 = Obj(midPoint = [3,3])
obj4 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj5 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2])

l = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]

list_no_duplicates = []

def Delete_duplicates(list1):        
    for i in list1:
        if i.midPoint not in list_no_duplicates.midPoint:
        list_no_duplicates.append(x)

Delete_duplicates(l)
print list_no_duplicates
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169252/remove-duplicates-in-list-of-object-with-python

Comment: `list_no_duplicates` is a list and doesn't have a `midPoint` attribute. If you wish to look at this attribute you need to have an `Object` object at hand. Also, what is `x` in the `list_no_duplicates.append(x)` line?

Comment: Do you want to maintain the order of the object in the new list?

Comment: do you want to remove those with >=2 entries, or just keep 1 of them?

Comment: Sorry, I meant i not x in 'list_no_duplicates.append(x)'.  Order does not need to be maintained and I would just like to keep 1 copy of those that are duplicated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) along with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to remove the duplicate entries from your list. For example:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> [next(obj) for i, obj in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.midPoint), lambda x: x.midPoint)]
[Obj: midPoint [1, 1], Obj: midPoint [2, 2], Obj: midPoint [3, 3]]
```

Here, I have added the [`__repr__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr) function to your `Obj` class to display the value of `midPoint` with your class' object:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Obj: midPoint {}'.format(str(self.midPoint))
```

**Note:** This solution won't maintain the order of elements in orginal list. The new list will be sorted based on the value of `midPoint`.

---

Below is the complete code for your reference:

```
from itertools import groupby

class Obj():
    def __init__(self, midPoint=[0,0]):
        self.midPoint = midPoint
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Obj: midPoint {}'.format(str(self.midPoint))

obj1 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj2 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2])
obj3 = Obj(midPoint = [3,3])
obj4 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj5 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2])

l = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
# `print(l)` will display:
# [Obj: midPoint [1, 1], Obj: midPoint [2, 2], Obj: midPoint [3, 3], Obj: midPoint [1, 1], Obj: midPoint [2, 2]]

# New list with unique `midPoint`s
new_list = [next(obj) for i, obj in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.midPoint), lambda x: x.midPoint)]
# `print(new_list)` will display:
# [Obj: midPoint [1, 1], Obj: midPoint [2, 2], Obj: midPoint [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter as ga
...
l2 = [next(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=ga('midPoint')), key=ga('midPoint'))]
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/ISOl/1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, this may work as you asked.

```
class Obj(): 
    def __init__(self, midPoint=[0,0]): 
        self.midPoint = midPoint

obj1 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj2 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2])
obj3 = Obj(midPoint = [3,3])
obj4 = Obj(midPoint = [1,1])
obj5 = Obj(midPoint = [2,2]) 

l = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
list_no_duplicates = [] 

# determines if midpoint already exists in any object inside list_no_duplicates
def midpoint_exists(midpoint):
    for obj in list_no_duplicates:
        if obj.midPoint == midpoint:
            return True
    return False

def Delete_duplicates(list1): 
    for obj in list1:
        # if there are no object with this midPoint, appends
        if not midpoint_exists(obj.midPoint):
            list_no_duplicates.append(obj)

Delete_duplicates(l)
print list_no_duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a dict, with setdefault, using the key as a tuple of the midPoint and the value as a list, which we then append to.

Then we have a dict with a list for each value of midPoint, and we can iterate out the [0]th element:

```
def Delete_duplicates(list1):
    deduped = {}
    for i in list1:
        deduped.setdefault(tuple(i.midPoint),[]).append(i)
    return [j[0] for i,j in deduped.items()]
```

If you want all those with duplicates removed, we can do the same, but return only if our lists length is 1:

```
def Delete_duplicates(list1):
    deduped = {}
    for i in list1:
        deduped.setdefault(tuple(i.midPoint),[]).append(1)
    return [i for i in list1 if len(deduped[tuple(i.midPoint)]) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the objects in the new list, you may use a `dict` to achieve this:

```
new_list = {tuple(obj.midPoint): obj  for obj in l}.values()

# content of `new_list` will be:
# [Obj: midPoint [3, 3], Obj: midPoint [1, 1], Obj: midPoint [2, 2]]
```

Create a dictionary with key as tuple of your `midPoint` value, and values as the object of `Obj` class. Then call `dict.values()` method to get the list of values i.e. list of `Obj` objects in your case.

However, in Python 3.x `dict.values()` return an object of `dict_values` type. In order to convert it to list, explicitly type-cast it to `list` as:

```
new_list = list(new_list)
```