# How to remove instance of custom object from python set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm playing around with some basic card/deck manipulations in python. Below you can see my Card class and Deck class. Assume that I know that some cards are dead and would like to remove them from the deck.

```
import itertools

SUIT_LIST = ("h", "s", "d", "c")
NUMERAL_LIST = ("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A")

class Card:
    def __init__(self, numeral, suit):
        self.numeral = numeral
        self.suit = suit
        self.card = self.numeral, self.suit
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.numeral + self.suit

class Deck(set):
    def __init__(self):
        for numeral, suit in itertools.product(NUMERAL_LIST, SUIT_LIST):
            self.add(Card(numeral, suit))

deck = Deck()    
dead_card = Card('J','s')
deck.remove(dead_card)
```

Raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-93-06af62ea1273>", line 23, in <module>
    deck.remove(dead_card)

KeyError: Js
```

What is the proper way of removing dead cards from my deck? And why the way I do it does not work?

Comment: Why not just store the cards as strings or tuples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need two new methods on your `Card` class, for membership in sets and dicts to work sanely:

```
class Card:
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.card)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Card):
            return self.card == other.card
        return NotImplemented
```

This is because sets are implemented with [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and unless you define how to hash and compare instances of your custom class, a hash based on the [identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) (memory location in CPython) will be used as a default.  Using `id` provides a fairly crappy default here - two cards with same number/suit would not be considered "equal" and the membership in a `Deck` is not recognised.

Comment: don't you need `__ne__` as well?

Comment: No, I don't believe you do here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The underlying algorithm uses ``__hash__`` to deduce positions in the hash table where an item *might* be. It then uses ``__eq__`` to test if is actually there, or just another object with the same hash. No other special method is used.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169252/remove-duplicates-in-list-of-object-with-python. Couldn't find a proper duplicate, a lot of q&a are similar, but nothing like this exactly.