# Python remove duplicates form multidimensional list

Tags: python

I have a list in python that looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "title": "Green Jacket",
        "price": "18",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Red Hat",
        "price": "5",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Green Jacket",
        "price": "25",
        "instock": "no",
    },
    {
        "title": "Purple Pants",
        "price": "100",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
]
```

I am trying to remove items from the list that have duplicate names, so in the example above the final list would look like this...

```
[
    {
        "title": "Green Jacket",
        "price": "18",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Red Hat",
        "price": "5",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Purple Pants",
        "price": "100",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
]
```

Is converting to a dict going to help me in this instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates in list of object with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169252/remove-duplicates-in-list-of-object-with-python)

Comment: Is it important which object remains in case of duplicate?

Comment: This first instance it finds should remain

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you expect:

```
lst1 = [
    {
        "title": "Green Jacket",
        "price": "18",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Red Hat",
        "price": "5",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
    {
        "title": "Green Jacket",
        "price": "25",
        "instock": "no",
    },
    {
        "title": "Purple Pants",
        "price": "100",
        "instock": "yes",
    },
]
titles = [item['title'] for item in lst1]
lst2 = [ lst1[ titles.index( title)] for title in set( titles)]
'''
```