# random.randrang constant image blitting

Tags: python, spring, pygame

I have a data structure I created myself, it's called `characters`.

This data structure has the following method

```
addCharacters(self, Character, number)
```

This allows the user to add as many characters to the screen. In this method, an array initialized in the `__init__` constructor is `append`ed to add the `Character` object.

I have a class `screen`, in this class I have the following method

```
addCharacter(self, Character, x, y)
```

this draws the character on the screen like so:

```
self.screen.blit(character.image,(x,y)
```

I call these methods in the main class where the code is run. a while loop to represent the game running is created. in this while loop the objects **must** be drawn, so `screen.blit` must happen in the while loop.

**Here is the problem**: when I call the method `myarray.addCharacter(character,4)` outside the while loop, and

```
for characters in charactersList:
     screen.addCharacter(character, random.randrange(0, screen.width), random.randrange(0,   world.screen))
```

The image **erratically** blits on the screen at different locations. I understand this is because of the `for` **loop inside** the **`while` loop**. I can't add the character outside the `while` loop as it won't draw to the screen.

Is there a way I can set the location of each object in this data structure all at a different position without constant blitting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want all characters at random locations Could you show me an example please?

Comment: BTW, is your data structure really called `characters`? If so, there might be another problem: After your `for` loop, that name will be bound to the last item from the `characterList` iterable and the class will no longer be available.

Comment: you explained it well, thanks I manged to do it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question correctly. As I understand it, you want to draw your "characters" at *random* positions of the screen, but those positions have to *stay the same* in each iteration of the outer `while` loop. I see two possibilities of doing this:

1. Either, add position attributes `x` and `y` to the `Character` class itself, if possible, or
2. use a dictionary for mapping `Character` objects to their `(x, y)` position.

I don't know what that `Character` class is (your own class, or from some library?), so the first may not be possible. For the second approch, `Character` objects need to be [hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/python-whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash). If that's not possible, too, you might be able to create a hashable wrapper class, or just use the object's [`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) for the mapping.

Code for approach 2 might look somewhat like this:

```
# create dictionary, defaulting to new random positions
randpos = lambda: (random.randrange(0, width), random.randrange(0, height))
d = collections.defaultdict(randpos)

for i in range(10):             # corresponds to your outer 'while' loop
    print "outer loop", i
    for k in range(5):          # your 'for characters...' loop
        x, y = d[k]             # get x, y from dict, default to random position
        print x, y              # use position
```