# How to quickly compute a hash for a collection of objects?

Tags: python, caching, hash, hashmap

Consider a function `f(*x)` which takes a lot of arguments `*x`. Based on these arguments (objects), the function `f` composes a rather complex object `o` and returns it. `o` implements `__call__`, so `o` itself serves as a function. Since the composition of `o` is pretty time consuming and in my scenario there is no point in having multiple instances of `o` based on the same arguments `*x`, they are to be cached.

The question is now: How to efficiently compute a hash based on multiple arguments `*x`? Currently I am using a python dictionary, and i concatenate the `str()` representations of each `x` to build each key. It works in my scenario, but it feels rather awkward. I need to call the resulting objects `o` in a very high frequency, so I suspect the repeated call of `str()` and the string concatenations waste a lot of computation time.

Comment: What are the types of the arguments in `*x`?

Comment: In my case, the arguments have a variety of types. I usually have tuples of integers, some floats and at least one str() representation of a context object coming from another library.

Comment: Then I would recommend simply calling [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) on the individual arguments in order to use the same hash Python uses internally to compare dictionary keys for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) built-in function, combining the hashes of the items in `x` together. The typical way to do this (see e.g. [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)) would be an `xor` across all the hashes of the individual objects:

> it is advised to somehow mix together (e.g. using exclusive or) the hash values for the components of the object that also play a part in comparison of objects

To implement that in a functional way, using [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce # only required in Python 3.x
from operator import xor

def hashed(*x):
    return reduce(xor, map(hash, x))
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2909106/3001761).

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.2, Python already contains an implementation of an LRU cache that you can use
to cache your functions' results based on their arguments: 
[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Example:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def f(*args):
    """Expensive function
    """
    print("f(%s) has been called." % (args, ))
    return sum(args)


print(f(1, 2, 3))
print(f(1, 2, 3, 4))
print(f(1, 2, 3))
print(f.cache_info())
```

Output:

```
f((1, 2, 3)) has been called.
6
f((1, 2, 3, 4)) has been called.
10
6
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=32, currsize=2)
```

*(Notice how `f(1, 2, 3)` only got called once)*

As suggested in the comments, it's probably best to simply use  the [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash)es of your arguments to build the cache-key for your arguments - that's what `lru_cache` already does for you.

If you're still on Python 2.7, Raymond Hettinger has posted some [recipes with LRU caches](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245/) that you could use in your own code.