# Creating array of unique objects in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, collections

Let's suppose I have a program that creates some scheme with lines and points.
All lines determine by two points. There are these classes:

```
class Coordinates(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        self.coordinates = coordinates

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates_1, coordinates_2):
        self.coordinates_1 = coordinates_1
        self.coordinates_2 = coordinates_2
```

A scheme takes list of lines and creates a list of unique points.

```
class Circuit(object):
    def __init__(self, element_list):
        self.line_list = element_list
        self.point_collection = set()
        self.point_collection = self.generate_points()

    def generate_points(self):
        for line in self.line_list:
            coordinates_pair = [line.coordinates_1, line.coordinates_2]
            for coordinates in coordinates_pair:
                self.point_collection.add(Point(coordinates))
        return self.point_collection
```

What variants are able to make a list or collection of unique objects? How to do it without using sets and sorting, only with loops and conditions? And how to do it simplier?

UPD. Code I attached doesn't work properly. I tried to add **hash** and **eq** methods in Point class:

```
class Point(object):
def __init__(self, coordinates):
    self.coordinates = coordinates

def __hash__(self):
    return 0

def __eq__(self, other):
    return True
```

Then I try to make a scheme with some lines:

```
element_list=[]
element_list.append(Line(Coordinates(0,0), Coordinates(10,0)))
element_list.append(Line(Coordinates(10,0), Coordinates(10,20)))

circuit = Circuit(element_list)

print(circuit.point_collection)
```

Two lines here equal four points, where two points have the same coordinates. Hence, the code must print three objects, but it does only one:

```
{<__main__.Point object at 0x0083E050>}
```

Comment: Using a set is not equivalent to sorting as a _set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects_. Can you explain why you don't want to use a set? This way we'll know what you are looking for.

Comment: @arekolek *Can you explain why you don't want to use a set?* - My guess is OP's professor/teacher said not to.

Comment: @Ian: Then, my question would become "why does the teacher want them not to use a set?".

Comment: The problem is that this code does not work. It just returns all points that it gets.  I want to know how to make it properly.
Also, I tried to create a recursive solution, but it confused me a bit. Therefore this way is interesting for me as well.

Comment: About the fact that the collection is not equivalent to sorting. I didn't mean sets then I said about sorting but I know an algorithm of creating unique lists then primary list sorts, and then it is easy to find an unique items. It works well

Comment: @IanAuld You made a goo guess but it's false. My speciality in university is not programming, I code just for self-education

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some remarks about your code, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You need to implement `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` methods in your `Point` class.
For an idea, see this [answer showing *a correct and good way to implement `__hash__()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909119/1916449).

**Long answer:**

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) says that:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include (...) removing duplicates from a sequence (...)

And [hashable means](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-hashable):

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a [`__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an [`__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#id).

Which explains why your code does not remove duplicate points.

Consider this implementation that makes all instances of `Foo` distinct and all instances of `Bar` equal:

```
class Foo:
  pass


class Bar:
  def __hash__(self):
    return 0

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return True
```

Now run:

```
>>> set([Foo(), Foo()])
{<__main__.Foo at 0x7fb140791da0>, <__main__.Foo at 0x7fb140791f60>}

>>> set([Bar(), Bar()])
{<__main__.Bar at 0x7fb1407c5780>}
```

In your case, `__eq__` should return `True` when both coordinates are equal, while `__hash__` should return a hash of the coordinate pair. See the answer mentioned earlier for a good way to do this.

**Some remarks:**

Your `Point` class has currently [no reason to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) from a design perspective, since it is just a wrapper around `Coordinates` and offers no additional functionality. You should just use either one of them, for example:

```
class Point(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

And why not call `coordinates_1` and `coordinates_2` just `a` and `b`?

```
class Line(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

Also, your `generate_points` could be implemented in a more pythonic way:

```
def generate_points(self):
  return set(p for l in self.line_list for p in (l.a, l.b))
```

Finally, for easier debugging, your might [consider implementing `__repr__` and `__str__` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/python-how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print) in your classes.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add __hash__ and __eq__ methods as you advised, I get only one item in the set in any case. I tried to implement instance variables in your Bar class. For example  `set([Bar(5), Bar(6)])` gives me only one object.

Comment: @hopheylalaley Can you edit your question to include your implementation of `__hash__` and `__eq__`?

Comment: Done. And thanks a lot for advices about code design. Though, I planned to distinguish Coordinates and Point classes. I want to make a program that makes a graphical realisation of graphs. Point means node or vertex of a graph here and it is supposed to have methods for finding adjacent nodes for instance.

Comment: @hopheylalaley I've linked to an answer that shows you how to implement them correctly.