# Python multiprocessing pool with shared data

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm attempting to speed up a multivariate fixed-point iteration algorithm using multiprocessing however, I'm running issues dealing with shared data. My solution vector is actually a named dictionary rather than a vector of numbers. Each element of the vector is actually computed using a different formula. At a high level, I have an algorithm like this:

```
current_estimate = previous_estimate
while True:
for state in all_states:
    current_estimate[state] = state.getValue(previous_estimate)
if norm(current_estimate, previous_estimate) < tolerance:
    break
else:
    previous_estimate, current_estimate = current_estimate, previous_estimate
```

I'm trying to parallelize the for-loop part with multiprocessing. The `previous_estimate` variable is read-only and each process only needs to write to one element of `current_estimate`. My current attempt at rewriting the for-loop is as follows:

```
# Class and function definitions
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    # representative getValue function
    def getValue(self, est):
        return est[self] + self.val

def worker(state, in_est, out_est):
    out_est[state] = state.getValue(in_est)

def worker_star(a_b_c):
    """ Allow multiple arguments for a pool
        Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5443941/3865495
    """
    return worker(*a_b_c)

# Initialize test environment
manager = Manager()
estimates = manager.dict()
all_states = []
for i in range(5):
     a = A(i)
     all_states.append(a)
     estimates[a] = 0

pool = Pool(process = 2)
prev_est = estimates
curr_est = estimates
pool.map(worker_star, itertools.izip(all_states, itertools.repeat(prev_est), itertools.repreat(curr_est)))
```

The issue I'm currently running into is that the elements added to the `all_states` array are not the same as those added to the `manager.dict()`. I keep getting `key value` errors when trying to access elements of the dictionary using elements of the array. And debugging, I found that none of the elements are the same.

```
print map(id, estimates.keys())
>>> [19558864, 19558928, 19558992, 19559056, 19559120]
print map(id, all_states)
>>> [19416144, 19416208, 19416272, 19416336, 19416400]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the objects you're putting into the `estimates` `DictProxy` aren't actually the same objects as those that live in the regular dict. The `manager.dict()` call returns a `DictProxy`, which is proxying access to a `dict` that actually lives in a completely separate manager process. When you insert things into it, they're really being copied and sent to a remote process, which means they're going to have a different identity.

To work around this, you can define your own `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions on `A`, as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/python-whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val

    # representative getValue function
    def getValue(self, est):
        return est[self] + self.val

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

    def __key(self):
        return (self.val,)

    def __eq__(x, y):
        return x.__key() == y.__key()
```

This means the key look ups for items in the `estimates` will just use the value of the `val` attribute to establish identity and equality, rather than the `id` assigned by Python.