# Equality and inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance, equality

When reading about how to implement `__eq__` in python, such as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash), you get recommendations like

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._a, self._b) == (other._a, other._b)
```

Now, I'm having problems when combining this with inheritance. Specifically, if I define a new class

```
class B(A):
    def new_method(self):
        return self._a + self._b
```

Then I get this issue

```
>>> a = A(1, 2)
>>> b = B(1, 2)
>>> a == b
True
```

But clearly, `a` and `b` are not the (exact) same!

What is the correct way to implement `__eq__` with inheritance?

Comment: How are you defining equality? Is `type` an important part of your equality test, e.g. `1 == True` is `True` but obviously they are not the same type. From an `a` perspective isn't `b` equal to the `a`. You may implement equality differently for `b`, `a == b` but that doesn't mean `b == a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that instances of different (sub)classes should not be equal, consider comparing their types as well:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self._a, self._b, type(self)) == (other._a, other._b, type(other))
```

In this way `A(1, 2) == B(1,2)` returns `False`.

Answer (score 4):

When performing a comparison between objects of two types where one type is derived from the other, Python ensures that the operator method is called on the derived class (in this case, `B`).

So to ensure that `B` objects compare dissimilarly to `A` objects, you can define `__eq__` in `B`:

```
class B(A):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, B) and super(B, self).__eq__(other)
```

Comment: @AChampion `B.__eq__` overrides `A.__eq__`, so `a == b` calls `B.__eq__(b, a)`. [Example](https://ideone.com/x0LQAo).

Comment: Bad assumption on my part, thanks. Is there rational for this given `a` is of type `A` not `B`.