# How to make same instance with same arguments but different for different arguments in python

Tags: python, singleton

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

a1 = A('a')        
a2 = A('a') 
b = A('b') 

print (a1==a2)
print (a1==b)
```

result should be True for first but False for second. I knew some way to implement singleton in Python. But all of them only generate one instance for every call. How do we link the __new__ method to __init__?

Comment: Do you want a1 and a2 to be separate but equal objects?

Comment: define `def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.fn == other.fn` and the `==` operator is redefined to match your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to think about singletons here and no reason to do anything with `__new__`. If you want two instances to be considered equal based on some condition, then you need to define `__eq__`.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, A) and self.fn == other.fn
```

(Note, `fn` is usually used as a holder for functions; you should think of another attribute name.)

Comment: I was going to answer that (except for the `isinstance` part). Maybe you should add that the `==` should be redefined if `fn` and `self.fn` can be 2 different class instances bearing the same values (and on, and on)

Comment: also `isinstance(other, A)` should probably be `type(other) == A` to restrict to actual `A` objects, not children

Comment: Thank you for you help. How about if I want to make a1 is a2 equal True?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a singleton you're looking for.
A singleton is when your class can produce only one instance at the time, so that you will have `A('a') is A('b')` True.

What can be deduced from your example is you're looking to define `__eq__`, which has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes).
Note that if you want to test equality for custom objects, you may have to define `__hash__`, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash)