# What are inside the __eq__() method by default

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read this (from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that x == y implies both that x is y and hash(x) == hash(y).

And I wish to know if the `__eq__()` method by default is defined like:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return hash(self) == hash(other)
```

Comment: That'd only work for things that are `hash`able then. How will you check for unhashable things ? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's more like:

```
def __eq__(self, other)
    return self is other
```

You can't use `hash()` because it's possible for different objects to have the same hash value.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the following reference: https://eev.ee/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/

in the default method where you just try to compare 2 objects while not override the ***eq*** it will see if they are the same 2 objects, more like the following:

```
def __eq__(self, other)
    return self is other
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash)

It explains how to use `__hash__()` with `__eq__()` correctly