# Hashing function for objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Does anyone know how the hashing function for objects works exactly? You can find online the answers for integers and strings, but not objects.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Integers and strings are objects

Comment: It calls the class's `__hash__` method.

Comment: It has to do with the way the object implemented the `__hash__` protocol

Comment: yes but integers are mod N, string use polynomial expansion to create hash functions. Objects I have no idea

Comment: @smac89 which is what exactly? this is the question. anyone can just call hash() and hope

Comment: Objects are composed of strings, tuples, integers, etc...so the hash of an object is simply a mixture of the hash of it's content

Comment: @smac89 still not clear to me exactly though

Comment: Unfortunately, the duplicate answer does not show good example of `__hash__`. Maybe this one will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash

Comment: *Everything* in Python is an object, so you'll have to specify exactly the types you are interested in.

Comment: @smac89 an object need not consist of any of those things, and need not hash on its content.