# Python: Can a custom mutable class be used as a key for a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, hashmap, networkx, hashtable

Let's say we have a custom node class like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next, random):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        self.random = random
```

I have a node object that I'd like to use  as a key for a dictionary.
My understanding is that an object should be immutable and hashable for it to be reliably used as a dictionary key, because a mutable object could result in a changing hash values and this object is mutable.

I know python does allow custom mutable objects to be used as dictionary keys, how does that work?

**Update**: Referenced links do not touch upon the mutability aspect of the custom object. They just provide a method to override the default implementation of the hash function. This question should be reopened as it is different from the referenced "duplicate" questions.

**Answer**: Default implementation of hash method for custom mutable object uses [identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for object's lifetime. A mutable custom object SHOULD NOT be overriding the default implementation of hash function. More detailed answer is provided below.

Comment: It partially answers my questions as it takes a very specific example where class has only one attribute of 'str' type which is immutable. I will answer this question as I figured how a class object with multiple attributes can be used as a key for dictionary even if it has attributes that are mutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a correct and good way to implement \_\_hash\_\_()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash)

Comment: @Anatolii I am afraid this question will have to be opened as reference links are not accurate answers for my question. Can it be done ?

Comment: Sure, but, in your question, you should explain why those links are not proper answers. Otherwise, you won't get enough upvotes (besides me) for reopening the question.

Comment: Done, I updated the question and also added a better improved answer.

Comment: I voted to reopen your question then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node custom object is mutable from its class definition and **any mutable object should not override the default implementation of hash method** as default method uses [identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for object's lifetime. Doing so ***might*** cause the hash value of the object to change and it can cause lot of problems.

For example:

```
Node node = new Node(5, None, None)
cache = {}
cache[node] = "Node added"
node.val = 5

# If we override default implementation of hash function, we have to
# make sure hashing function does not use object attributes else
# accessing cache[node] now would cause problem as a different hashed 
# value would be computed and we won't be able to retrieve "Node added" 
# value. 

# Default implementation uses identity and would always hash 
# to same value even if the object mutates.
```

But we can go ahead and override the hash method for an immutable object. Answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash) thread helped me understand how it works. For the following, **we are going to assume that attributes of Node object will never change once the object has been created.**

Idea here is to make sure your custom object implements hash and equality methods.

Equality method should be implemented in such a way that two logical equivalent object are always considered equal. For the given **Node** object here, two nodes would be considered equal if all their attributes are same. So we can build a key which is a tuple of all attributes. This works because tuples are immutable, so we are basically creating an immutable object containing all the attributes for the object and are going to use this for calculating hash.

Following implementation ensures that two logically equivalent nodes (having same attributes) have the same key and hence will generate the same hash value for two equal nodes.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next, random):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        self.random = random

    def __key(self):
        return (self.val, self.next, self.random)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Node):
            return self.__key() == other.__key()
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: It would be nice to make this a dataclass with frozen=True (and eq=False) to avoid mutation, as otherwise this class would fail to retrieve as a key in a python dictionary whenever any of its variables are changed after it had been inserted before their modification.

Comment: That's because once its hash value changes, the object can no longer be retrieved from the dictionary, as the object is stored in memory according to its original hash and the dict does rely on the hash value being constant across the lifecycle of the object having been inserted as a key, for being able to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom class containing mutable objects which does not override the default `__eq__` method, [it will just work out of the box](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). Also when using a dataclass with eq=False ...

> If eq and frozen are both true, by default dataclass() will generate a **hash**() method for you. If eq is true and frozen is false, **hash**() will be set to None, marking it unhashable (which it is, since it is mutable). If eq is false, **hash**() will be left untouched meaning the **hash**() method of the superclass will be used (if the superclass is object, this means it will fall back to id-based hashing).

So, in that vein, a dataclass with eq=False will consistently work as a dict key, hashing and checking equality by object id not by object contents:

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
class ExampleNode():
    a: np.array
    b: int


def test_ExampleNode():

    e1 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    d: dict = {e1: 'foo'}
    assert e1 in d and d[e1] == 'foo'

    e2 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(200), 2)
    d.update({e2: 'bar'})

    assert e1 in d and d[e1] == 'foo'
    assert e2 in d and d[e2] == 'bar'

    e3 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    d.update({e3: 'baz'})
    assert e1 in d and d[e1] == 'foo'
    assert e3 in d and d[e3] == 'baz'

    e1.a.fill(1)
    assert e1 in d and d[e1] == 'foo'

    # pickle and unpickle, now the keys are no longer the same memory objects, 
    # but we can still assert they are equal to the original keys preceding 
    # the pickling reliant upon dict keys being ordered as of python 3.7 or so.
    d = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d))
    unpickled_k1 = list(d.keys())[0]
    unpickled_k2 = list(d.keys())[1]
    unpickled_k3 = list(d.keys())[2]
    assert unpickled_k1.equals(e1)
    assert unpickled_k2.equals(e2)
    assert unpickled_k3.equals(e3)
```

Here, content-wise equal objects are not the same key in the dictionary, nor can they be compared with the standard equality operator outside of the dict, as you are not allowed to override the default `__eq__` for this to work for the dictionary.

The same would also hold, as mentioned, with a plain custom class:

```
class ExampleNode():
    def __init__(self, a: list, b: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def equals(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self.a, other.a) and self.b == other.b
```

This is because both a plain custom object, and a dataclass with eq=False, get a hash by id by default, and presumably also an equality by id default, which the dict will internally use when there are hashing collisions (bounty people?!)

---

Python's [dict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c) is highly optimized, yet at the same time it is a leaky unsafe abstraction, somewhat lacking concise clear documentation in that key regard. The suggested options above seem to be safe ― if mindfully used as intended.

As an aftermath, you may want to peak into how a library like NetworkX [designs around this limitation, here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#nodes-and-edges). Their definition of python's [hashing and immutability](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) is probably the most correct succinct one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers already given, but I just want to summarise the underlying process a little to hopefully shed a little more light on what is happening.

Answer in two parts. Theory first, then application to a mutable dict key.

### Theory

Firstly, consider adding a key:value pair to an empty dictionary.

- Hash value generated using object's `__hash__`

  - Objects will use the object id as the hash by default
- Location in hash table determined by using a mask on the hash based on the size of the dictionary
- The hash, key and value are then stored in the dictionary

  - I don't have a reference for this, but it must be pointers to the key and value

Now let's suppose we want to retrieve that value.

- Key is hashed as before
- Location in dictionary is determined by masking hash as above
- At the location our key leads us to we find the key used to save the value
- These keys are compared using `__eq__` (`==`)

  - Note not `is` - Hence why you can retrieve values using a different, immutable object
- If they are equal, the value is retrieved
- If not equal, python starts 'probing'

  - That means we have a hash collision

So hash collisions. Let's talk about those. Suppose I want to add a second key:value pair, which are different objects but will coincidentally end up creating a hash collision.

- Generate hash
- Generate location
- Arrive at location - not empty
- Quite common as a dict starts with 8 slots and only expands once 2/3 filled

  - So the mask creating a location will often lead to a location being filled already
- First compare hashes
- Hashes equal
- Now compare keys

  - Again using `__eq__`
- Now 'probe'
- Jump pseudo-randomly around the dict until finding an empty slot

  - Note: Repeatedly pseudo-randomly
- Place in first empty slot found

So that is what happens on hash collision on insertion. On lookup it is the same. If a key's slot is found to be full with a key with a different value, it probes in the same pseudo-random order as it would have when it placed something there before. Eventually it finds the key which evaluates `__eq__` as True with our key and returns the value.

Theory done.

### Mutable keys

Hopefully it is clear from my explanation above why you should not use mutable objects as keys. But let's talk about it anyway.

**Mutable key - hash based on ID**

Let's assume you create a mutable class to use as a key, but you don't override `__hash__` to be based on value and just use the default which is by ID. Now it is impossible (unless you are very fortunate and get a hash collision) to access that key with any instance of your key class unless it is the object you originally used.

And that will work perfectly fine, but you will end up with objects which compare equally with `__eq__` being separate keys in the dictionary.

**Mutable key - hash based on value**

Now is where things really go badly. Firstly, your key object is now tied to the dictionary in two ways.

- Its hash at the moment you inserted the key:value pair
- The object itself in whatever state it currently is

Now if you modify the object being used as a key it's hash will change meaning that you will not be able to even find the location in the hashmap of your key:value pair.

Of course, you can find the location of that key:value pair using a different key object which has the values of the first key as it was when you added the pair. But the problem is that once it finds the location, it compares them with `__eq__` and finds that they are NOT equal as the stored version of the key is actually the pointer to the original key whose value has since changed. As such, you now cannot access your original pair without resetting the values of the initial key.

**If you have to use a mutable object as a key**

Have a method/property in your object which creates an immutable representation of your object. Something like a tuple or string that encodes all of the relevant information of the object at that instant and use that whenever you need to.

eg.

```
class MutableThing:
    @property
    def key(self):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z, self.t)

object = MutableThing(x=0, y=1, z=2, t=3)
my_dict = {object.key: 42}
```

Please let me know if there are any further thoughts or if I have said anything incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Python's [dict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c) is highly optimized, yet at the same time it is a leaky unsafe abstraction, somewhat lacking concise clear documentation in that key regard.

I think when identity by object id is desired, the following works without disrupting the standard equality operator nor robust use as a dictionary key, as long as you consider keys following identity semantics not equality semantics in your code (meaning that you do not expect equal
objects to be interchangeable as keys).

Even if there's a hash collision for multiple hashed id's (extremely rare) then as far as I know python's `dict` will correctly store and locate the key object despite the colliding hash ― when retrieving the key it will first go to the dict's internal memory location determined by the hash, and then check for equality, if not equal it will proceed to the next memory cell or block, and correctly retrieve the desired object not the one having the same colliding hash value.

By providing hashing by id and equality by values, this flow is facilitated, as long you don't mutate the internal values of your object.

To avoid mutating the interval values of your objects you can use a frozen dataclass, a `flags.writeable = False` numpy array, and avoid the use of mutable collections like lists (and regular dicts).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np


@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False)
class ExampleNode():
    a: np.array
    b: int

    def __hash__ (self):
        return hash(id(self))
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self.a, other.a) and self.b == other.b

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.a.flags.writeable = False


def test_self_identity_and_equality():

    n = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    assert n is n
    assert n == n


def test_identity():

    n1 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    n2 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)

    assert n1 == n2
    assert n1 is not n2


def test_non_identity():

    n1 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    n2 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(200), 1)
    assert n1 != n2
    assert n1 is not n2


def test_dict_key_behavior():

    n1 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    n2 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)

    d: dict = {n1: 'n1', n2: 'n2'}
    assert n1 == n2
    assert n1 in d and d[n1] == 'n1'
    assert n2 in d and d[n2] == 'n2'
    assert len(d) == 2
    assert d[n1] is not d[n2]


def test_dict_behavior_elaborate_1():

    n1 = ExampleNode(np.ones(100), 1)
    n2 = ExampleNode(np.ones(100), 1)

    d: dict = {n1: n2, n2: n1}
    assert n1 in d and d[n1] == n2
    assert n2 in d and d[n2] == n1

    assert d[n1] is not n1
    assert d[n1] is n2
    assert d[n2] is not n2
    assert d[n2] is n1

def test_dict_behavior_elaborate_2():

    n1 = ExampleNode(np.zeros(100), 1)
    n2 = ExampleNode(np.ones(100), 1)

    d: dict = {n1: n2, n2: n1}
    assert n1 in d and d[n1] == n2
    assert n2 in d and d[n2] == n1

    assert d[n1] is not n1
    assert d[n1] is n2
    assert d[n2] is not n2
    assert d[n2] is n1
```

As an aftermath, you may want to peak into how a library like NetworkX [designs around this limitation, here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#nodes-and-edges). Their definition of python's [hashing and immutability](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) is probably the most correct succinct one out there.

Comment: Don't do this. Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value. There are many nasty surprises if you implement an incoherent `__hash__` + `__eq__` like this.

Comment: Right. For intuition, what would be the direct consequences of violating this?

Comment: You get insane behavior from many data structures.  `e1 in {e2}` can be False but `e1 == {e2}.pop()` is true.  dicts are often used for caching / memos, so those all break.

Comment: If the `__eq__` is value based, the `__hash__` needs to be value-based too.  Based on `a.tobytes()`, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks again, but that said, if in your code you don't consider different-yet-identical objects to be interchangeable as keys, then wouldn't `e1 not in {e2} and e1 == {e2}.pop()` be coherent under such semantics? your object `e1` is not in the set but what is in the set is equal to it but not the same identity. This seems coherent to me as following identity semantics being detached from equality of contents. Where does that break as well please?