# Python dict.get(k) returns none even though key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Perhaps my understanding of python's dictionary is not good. But here's the problem.

Does it ever happen that a `{yolk: shell}` pair **exists** in the dictionary say `eggs`, but a `eggs.get(yolk)` can return `None`?

So, in a large code, I do multiple `get` operations for a dictionary, and after certain iterations, I observe this situation.

```
   >>> for key, value in nodehashes.items():
   ...    print(key, nodehashes.get(key), value)
   ............................
   ...........................
   <Graph.Node object at 0x00000264128C4DA0> 3309678211443697093 3309678211443697093
   <Graph.Node object at 0x00000264128C4DD8> 3554035049990170053 3554035049990170053
   <Graph.Node object at 0x00000264128C4E10> None -7182124040890112571  # Look at this!!
   <Graph.Node object at 0x00000264128C4E48> 3268020121048950213 3268020121048950213
   <Graph.Node object at 0x00000264128C4E80> -1243862058694105659 -1243862058694105659
   ............................
   ............................
```

At first sight, It looks like somewhere in the code, the key is deleted, but then how does `nodehashes.items()` return the correct key-value pair? I swept the entire region, I am not popping an item at all. How can this happen?

I know it's wrong on my part not to post an example, but I really don't know where to start looking in the code, The Nodes are hashed in the beginning and they are only accessed with `get`. Surprisingly, even PyCharm's debugger shows the key-value pair to exist. But the `get` returns None. So if anyone else has hit upon this before, I am all ears.

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    if (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y): 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 

def __hash__(self): 
    return hash(tuple([self.x, self.y]))
```

Comment: Is this concurrent code? Is it possible there's another thread/... that can be modifying `nodehashes` as you're iterating over it?

Comment: No, it is not concurrent.

Comment: does `class Node` define a `__hash__` and/or `__eq__`?

Comment: I tried to build a reproducible example, but I'm unable to get it to reproduce this scenario.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the classs Node defines both as `
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple([self.x, self.y]))`

Comment: When giving more code, edit your post to add it, not in comment, (ive done it for you now)

Comment: Alright, thanks @azro, a bit new here, sorry!

Comment: look at the answer by @schwobaseggl I suspect you've mutated your `Node` objects in a way that affects their hash or equality, after you've added them to your dict. Hashing/equality **must be consistent**. This is why "hashable" is often synonymous with "immutable"

Comment: What is the reason for overriding `__eq__` and `__hash__` in the first place?

Comment: @AKX.  `__eq__` to check if two nodes are equivalent in x, y. Coming to `__hash__`. In another class, I build a dictionary with `{nodehash, index}` where `nodehash` is `hash(x,y)` and `index` is the index of the vertex in a [vertex buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) with positions and colours. So I though hashing by position would be a unique way to ID a node, but as it turns out that was stupid design pattern and I could just override __hash__ to return object's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reproduce that if you have a custom `__hash__` method on mutable objects:

```
class A:
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.a)

>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.a = 1
>>> a2.a = 2
>>> d = {a1: 1, a2: 2}
>>> a1.a = 3
>>> d.items()
dict_items([(<__main__.A object at 0x7f1762a8b668>, 1), (<__main__.A object at 0x7f17623d76d8>, 2)])
>>> d.get(a1)
None
```

You can see that `d.items()` still has access to both `A` objects, but `get` can't find it anymore, because the `hash`  value has changed.

Comment: Well, any hash method that is inconsistent with equality. consider the behavior of `float('nan')` in hashing data structures. But I suspect your guess is correct.

Comment: @juanpa Inconsistencies are a problem, but in your case the code would be completely deterministic which it clearly isn't here.

Comment: Huh, this actually explains it, so I'd have to think of another way of IDing a node other than the __hash__ method.

Comment: @JaswantP or better yet, use immutable nodes.

Comment: @juanpa nan would never equals nan, so the node would never be found. It's more likely the classic mistake of using mutable properties for a hash. One downside of Python is that it can't easily warn you about these downsides, in say C# this would be a static compiler warning.

Comment: @JaswantP you could use `id(node)` as key in your dict.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's not possible, the program allows user to move around nodes, so they should be mutable.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, so that would mean the object id right? That's perfect then.

Comment: @JaswantP of course it is *possible*. There are entire languages and programming paradigms that *don't allow* mutable state.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, so you're saying I can initialize Node with attributes x, y and then change them later but still retain the id? Although, I think I unnecessarily redefined `__hash__` when the default is what I need.

Comment: @JaswantP well, yes, the id will be the same. I forgot, though, that if you define an `__eq__` and not a `__hash__` then `__hash__` is implicitely set to `None` which will raise a type error when you try to hash it. So you could just use `__hash__ = object.__hash__` or define it yourself to just retur `id(self)`