# Is there a function that can turn a string into a hash?

Tags: python, hash

Ideally, 14 characters? Or, whatever works.

Comment: Yes, it is called a **hash** function ;)

Comment: Seriously, @TIMEX, 737 questions in under 14 months of registration? That's almost two a day on average - much higher at times! And many of them are oh-so-basic questions which you could find answers for with a trivial search. Frankly, you would make more efficient use of your time and the time of others if you tried searching the web and StackOverflow before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Built in python hash() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793761/built-in-python-hash-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html)

This module implements a common interface to many different secure hash and message digest algorithms. Included are the FIPS secure hash algorithms SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 as well as RSA’s MD5 algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

14 hex digits is 56 bits.
14 base64 digits is 84 bits.

md5 is 128 bits, and sha1 is 160, so you could use a truncation of those - both can be generated by hashlib, along with other more recent sha2 hashes.

Which hash is appropriate depends on what the purpose of the hash is.