# Convert String to Decimal in Python

Tags: python, string, decimal

We can convert a `datetime` value in to decimal using following function.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now()
t1 = t.timetuple()

print time.mktime(t1)
```

Output :

```
Out[9]: 1395136322.0
```

Similarly is there a way to convert strings in to a `decimal` using python?.

Example string.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

Comment: What's the expected output???

Comment: @Jayanth Koushik : It's ok to get a float/int output.

Comment: Maybe you are mis-understanding ``time.mktime()``. It returns the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. Thus instead of representing dates as (day, month, year) since Jesus, it represents times/dates as seconds since 1970. There's not really an analogous representation for arbitrary strings.

Comment: @Christian Aichinger : It's ok it shows the numberof seconds, I just need get a numerical value for a string, and always if the same string is presented same numerical value should be produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hash](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#hash) function:

```
>>> hash("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
1892010093
```

Comment: Hey ndpu, I get negative values? for the abouve one I got -3723762795795855251.

Comment: yeah; hash depends on a lot of things. it is possible for the value to be negative.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793761/built-in-python-hash-function

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Note that the `hash` might not be always the same for the same string. If hash randomization is turned on different executions of the interpreter will result in different hashes.

Comment: @ndpu : Yes, hashing works :) Thanks...abs(hash(s)) % (10 ** 8) can be used to get 8 digit representation(or any number of digits).

Answer (score 3):

If you want an integer to uniquely identify a string, I'd go for hashing functions, like SHA. They return the same value for the same input.

```
import hashlib
def sha256_hash_as_int(s):
    return int(hashlib.sha256(s).hexdigest(), 16)
```

If you use Python 3, you first have to encode `s` to some concrete encoding, like UTF-8.

Furthermore, take a look at the `hashlib` module and decide if you really need an integer, or if the output of `hexdigest()` isn't OK for you, too.

Comment: What about this? abs(hash(s)) % (10 ** 8) Will it always generate same number for same string.(Up to now my experiment strings always gave me the same number)

Comment: It depends on your needs. ``hash(s)`` isn't constant between different Python versions and even between different Python sessions (newer Python versions only, due to [hash randomization](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703)). The ``hashlib`` functions are designed to always give the same output for the same input.