# Perl's equivalent of Python's hash (or Java's hashCode) function?

Tags: python, perl, hash

The summary documentation for Python's `hash` function reads:

```
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in function hash>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:
hash(object) -> integer

Return a hash value for the object.  Two objects with the same value have
the same hash value.  The reverse is not necessarily true, but likely.
```

(For example, the `hash` function when applied to the documentation string above returns the integer 3071661466461282235.)

Is there an equivalent function for Perl?

EDIT: What I'm looking for does not need to return the same value as Python's `hash` function for any argument.

Comment: Are you looking for *any* hashing function or one that specifically gives the same results as Python's (at least for primitive values)

Comment: @Quentin: thanks for your question; I've added a clarification to my post.  In short, agreement with Python's `hash` is not necessary (though, now that you mention it, it would be kind of nice, but only as a pleasant bonus, not at all required).

Comment: `sub hash { return unpack("%32W*", "@_") }` as the python function makes sense only for the strings? http://stackoverflow.com/a/793835/223226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways of hashing an object. The best way to do this with perl is via a module.

E.g. [`Digest::SHA`](http://search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.95/lib/Digest/SHA.pm)

Which would work like this:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha1 sha1_hex sha1_base64 ...);

$digest = sha1($data);
$digest = sha1_hex($data);
$digest = sha1_base64($data);

$digest = sha256($data);
$digest = sha384_hex($data);
$digest = sha512_base64($data);
```

You can see a list of the various choices by running `i /Digest/` in the CPAN shell `perl -MCPAN -e shell`. `Digest::MD5` is another common choice for this.

I would suggest for trivial implementations, it doesn't actually make much difference which you use. If it's non trivial then there are security concerns relating to hash collisions.

Comment: That will hash a string of bytes. That may or may not be what the needs.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should overload "to-string" method of your object. It might be enough if you want just to use objects as keys in hashes. Perl applies some internal hash mechanism for quick **key-value** access.

Second, you can apply any hashing mechanism to the resulting string, e.g. [Digest::SHA](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA), or, if you don't need strong security requirements, then yo can use [Digest::MurmurHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MurmurHash) (The announced speed for MurmurHash is **5Gb/s** !).