# gene extraction from a fasta file according to sequence with biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I have a fasta file that I am parsing. The file is composed of several sequences that belongs to the same gene from a different bacterial strain. What I want to do, and the script does is to check if the sequence are equal or different to the reference seq. With that information I want to produce a new file BUT I only one one sequence of each.

```
def checking_sequences():
gene_records=list(SeqIO.parse('/files/gene_A.fasta', 'fasta'))
ref_id=gene_records[-1].id
ref_seq=gene_records[-1].seq
#print gene_records[-1].description
output_handle=open('//files/' + 'corrected_gene_1', 'a')
print len(gene_records)
count=0
dif_count=0
reference_list=[]

for gene_record in gene_records:
    #count+=1
    if len(gene_record.seq) == len(ref_seq):
    #print len(gene_records.seq)
    #print len(ref_seq)
        print 'Found all lengths are equal'                     
    else:
        print 'Found %s sequence with different lengths' % (gene_records.description)

    ###checking sequence equality
    if gene_record.seq==ref_seq:
        count+=1
        gene_record.id=gene_record.id +'_0'
        reference_list.append(gene_record)
        ref_count=reference_list.count(gene_record.seq)
        print 'There are %i sequences are  equal to the reference sequence' %(count)    
    else:       
        dif_count+=1
        reference_list.append(gene_record.seq)
        seq_count=reference_list.count(gene_record.seq)
        gene_record.id=gene_record.id +'_'+ str(dif_count)
        print 'Found  %i  different that ref_seq' % (seq_count)
        print 'xxxxxxxxxxx'




        #print seq_count
        #print len(reference_list)  
    SeqIO.write(gene_record, output_handle, 'fasta')


output_handle.close()
```

checking_sequences()
For some clarification :

```
original file                           desire output
    >gene_1 strainIDx                     >gen1_strainIDx
    seqA                                    seqA
    >gene_1 strainIDy                      >gene_1 strainIDy
   seqB                                       seqB
    >gene_1 strainIDz
    seqA
```

I don't mind about the ID just I would like to have one seq of each. I have tried to use 'break'but I don't get the output I would like to. Help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: I have never heard of hash so I didn't know what it does or doesn't.

Reference:

> Built-in Functions [hash(object)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)
>   Return the hash value as integers.
>   They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup.
>
> SO QA [Built in python hash() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793761/built-in-python-hash-function)

---

> **Question**:  I want to produce a new file BUT only one sequence of each.

Use a Lookup Table, for example:

```
lookup = Set()

with open('/files/' + 'corrected_gene_1', "w") as handle: 
    for record in SeqIO.parse('/files/gene_A.fasta', "fasta"):
        seq_hash = hash(str(record.seq))

        if not seq_hash in lookup:
            # Not in lookup, save
            lookup.add(seq_hash)
            SeqIO.write(records, handle, "fasta")
        else:
            # already saved - Skip
            pass
```

Comment: And in wihich part of my script I should place it, please?

Comment: I don't understand your code very much. Before I create my file I firstly need to see if len(seq) are equal. If there are equal then I add them to the file. Now I'm very puzzled.

Comment: @Ana: Equal Length don't mean equal sequence, but equal `hash` does. My Example code **filters** all duplicate sequence. If you need another Condition [Edit] your Question accordingly.

Comment: @stovfl Why adding an `else` statement? seems unnecessary here

Comment: @rodgdor: Remove it if don't need it. You can use it for Statistics e.g. count, print or write to another File duplicate sequence.

Comment: @stovfl: I have never heard of hash so I didn't know what it does or doesn't. But if it short my code, I will be very happy using it. I am going to get some reading about it. If you know a nice link just let me know. One is always learning new things! Thanks.